# Why do I still need @inject in this angular2 example?

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, factory-pattern

This is proably a special case (injecting the browsers native window object), but nevertheless I'm a bit confused about why I still need the @Inject() parameter-decorator when my class already has a @Injectable() decorator.

Take this simplified example:

```js
import { provide, bootstrap, Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class Token {
  private token: string;

  public constructor(token: string, window: Window) {
    this.token = window.atob(token);
  };

  public getToken(): string {
    return this.token;
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class TokenFactory {
  private window: Window;

  public constructor(window: Window) {
    this.window = window;
  }

  public createToken(token: string): Token {
    return new Token(token, this.window);
  }
}


@Component({
  template:   `
    <p *ngFor="let token of tokens">
      Encoded: {{token.getToken()}}
    </p>
  `,
  providers:  [ TokenFactory ]
})
class MainComponent {
  public tokens: Token[];

  public constructor(factory: TokenFactory) {
    this.tokens = [
      factory.create('token-1'),
      factory.create('token-2')
    ];
  };
}


bootstrap(
  MainComponent, [
    provide(Window, { useValue: window })
]);
```

**Overview:** We have a token class that represents an object that could exist multiple times inside a component or another service (so no singleton). The token class depends on the global window object (eg. for base64 encoding).
To make this testable we define an app-wide provider for the global [window object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) during bootstrap instead of using it directly in the token service.

The main component needs to create tokens dynamically, so we create and inject a simple factory-service *TokenFactory* which also needs the window provider (to pass it the the token class during construction).

**The Problem:** This fails when executed in a browser with the error

```
Can't resolve all parameters for TokenFactory: (?).
```

but can be fixed by adding a @Inject(Window) decorator to the factories constructor *window* parameter.

Now, I'm a bit confused, since most guides/tutorials explain that the inject decorator is not required in typescript when decorating the class with the Injectable decorator, *so why does the example fail without using @Inject() decorator*?

**Config:** *emitDecoratorMetadata* and *experimentalDecorators* settings are enabled and I'm using *tsc 1.8.10* and *angular2 rc.3*.

---

**PS:** *I'm also open for general design improvements.*

*(Eg. In a production scenario I would probably only export the Token interface and not the whole class)*

Comment: Could you tell more about where the Window class is defined and how you import it? Thanks!

Comment: Its the browsers global [window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) exposed as _window_ (lover case). It gets injected at the bottom during bootstrap. Hm..., could it be that the provider-name must be a string or better an OpaqueToken in this case, since typescript/angular might confuse the Window name property?

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is a run-time (browser) error not compile-time (tsc)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unclear to me what the question actually is about but

type `string` for a constructor parameter of an injectable doesn't make any sense without `@Inject(...)`

```
@Injectable()
export class Token {
  private token: string;

  public constructor(token: string, window: Window) { // <<== invalid
    this.token = window.atob(token);
  };

  public getToken(): string {
    return this.token;
  }
}
```

but because you are using it like

```
new Token(token, this.window);
```

it seems that just `@Injectable()` should be removed from this class.

---

About the error message: It looks like `Window` is not properly imported or it is not a type but an `OpaqueToken` or a `string`.

`@Inject()` is required if a key that differs from the parameter type should be used by dependency injection. In your case it looks like `Window` is not a type (class) and therefore doesn't work when used as such.

Comment: Nice catch, you are right I should drop the injectable for the Token class, since the _token_ parameter is not intended to be injected but actually more of an input parameter. Your comment about window rings a bell, since the window _object_ comes from the browser it is probably not decorated (no metadata) and thus angular needs the Inject docorator on the factories window parameter; Sounds right.